# ios draw image on canvas with display:none causes memory leak

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad, canvas

These two jsfiddle links code are equal except that one has its canvas in a div with display:none. The thing is that on an iPad, the one with `display:none` crashes after a few seconds and the other one keeps on going...

http://jsfiddle.net/MesK7/    (display:none , crashes)

```
display:none
```

also the other working jsfiddle link (which I cannot post due to lack of reputation, has the following key: yNNxL

Is this a known bug? I have done some googling and did not find a solution.
(Building an application where we need to load images on canvasses that should not be visible to the user while they are loading).

I would appreciate some input on this.

This is tested on:
iPad 1 , 5.1.1
iPad 2 , 5.1.1

Win7/Chrome  29.0.1547.66 m  (works on both jsfiddle links)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
visibility:hidden;
```

When and element is `display:none;` it has no dimensions.